# golang buffer channel unexpected result

Tags: go

```
package main
import (
    "time"
    "runtime"
)

var c = make(chan int, 2)

func main() {
  go worker(1)
  for i := 0; i < 30; i++ {
    go func() {
            // k := i   make a local copy not make any difference
            c <- i
    }()
  }
  time.Sleep(100* time.Second)
}

func worker(id int) {
  for {
    a := <-c
    println(a, runtime.NumGoroutine())
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
  }
}
```

the output is unpredictable, sometimes like below.

```
7 9
13 29
13 28
13 27
13 26
13 25
13 24
13 23
16 22
16 21
17 20
19 19
21 18
21 17
23 16
25 15
26 14
26 13
26 12
26 11
26 10
26 9
26 8
26 7
27 6
27 5
13 4
28 3
30 2
30 2
```

I know sender will block if the buffer channel is full, and when channel is available the sender can continue.

1. why output is not constant output 0-29? how to make it??
2. how variable/local variable store in goroutine??
3. if lots of senders are blocked, are they waked up by FIFO order??

Comment: 1: Because the goroutine execute _concurrently_. Don't use goroutines. 2. See https://golang.org/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines for your problem. 3. No, not at all.

Answer (score 2):

Output is not constant because different goroutines share same local variable i. If you uncomment your line and move it right before the goruoutine call, you'll see constant output 0-29. The better way is to move i variable to goroutine function arguments.

Wake up order is not specified in specs. You should consider it as a random one.

Answer (score 0):

3 It is FIFO

1 Because the goroutines created inside the for loop will not necessarily execute sequentially. The underlying Go scheduler will start one randomly (it's how channels dispatch their values). Of-course all of them will get created, but they will (get scheduled to) start at the point `time.Sleep(...)` in `main` is called (Go scheduler is a cooperative one and does so on certain points like function calls, channel ops, etc - for example [this](http://blog.nindalf.com/how-goroutines-work/))

2 Use the channel directly:

```
var (
    c  = make(chan int, 2)
    wg = &sync.WaitGroup{}
)

func main() {
    wg.Add(1)
    go worker(1)

    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        for i := 0; i < 30; i++ {
            c <- i
        }
        close(c)
    }()
    wg.Wait()
}

func worker(id int) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for a := range c {
        println(a, runtime.NumGoroutine())
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
    }
}
```

About passing a `for` loop variable; you've done it almost correctly. You just have to put the line to create the local closure, outside the goroutine:

```
var (
    wg = &sync.WaitGroup{}
)

func main() {
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        localClosure := i // <- this line

        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            println(localClosure)
        }()
    }

    wg.Wait()
}
```